# Add custom claims to azure b2c client credentials flow

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-api-management, apim

I have configured b2c as an Authorization Server for client credentials flow, I would like to add a claim to the token, so I could send it to the backend service in APIM using policy.
But I could not find a way to add this extra claim to the token so I could use it on the APIM.
Note: it was possible using Authorization Code flow, but the claims are not being passed through the request when using client credentials.

Is there a way for achieving that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do claims customization with Azure AD [client_credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow). We will release Azure AD B2C client credential flow, which will allow claims customization using a custom policy, similar to authorization code flow, in the future.

Comment: Is there any documentation or public roadmap, where we can follow the progress of the release of this feature?

Comment: I believe this is now available https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/client-credentials-grant-flow

Comment: Yes, that’s right!

Comment: Hi @JasSuri-MSFT @smurtagh, I have a similar question about setting the value of a claim using the MSAL library (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74820291/unable-to-set-client-claims-when-acquiring-confidential-client-application-token?noredirect=1#comment132045536_74820291)

I was unable to determine how to set the `preferred_username` claim using the documentation you linked?

Answer (score 0):

Facing this issue myself, I documented the steps to get there.

#### 1 Set up the resource app and client as usual

So, first, configure the client credentials flow as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/client-credentials-grant-flow?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

This is pretty straight forward, up till (and including) step 3.
About step 3: pay attention to this line:

> Replace  with the full name of your user flow, or custom policy. **Note, all types of user flows and custom policies support client credentials flow.** You can use any user flow or custom policy you have, or create a new one, such as sign-up or sign-in.

It notes all user flows support `client_credentials`, however, although, when targetting a user flow, the API connector (which can normally be used to enrich a token will not be called).

#### 2 Prepare the custom policies

As by [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy), set up signing and encryption keys:

##### Create the signing key

- Select Policy Keys and then select Add.
- For Options, choose Generate.
- In Name, enter TokenSigningKeyContainer. The prefix B2C_1A_ might be added automatically.
- For Key type, select RSA.
- For Key usage, select Signature.
  Select Create.

##### Create the encryption key

- Select Policy Keys and then select Add.
- For Options, choose Generate.
- In Name, enter TokenEncryptionKeyContainer. The prefix B2C_1A_ might be added automatically.
- For Key type, select RSA.
- For Key usage, select Encryption.
- Select Create.

##### Upload base policies

Install the base policies from the [starter pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#get-the-starter-pack), also see [github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack)

There are several similar files, but the ones under **LocalAccounts** are sufficient for just enriching the JWT.

Make sure you replace the tenant name with yours.

Upload these into the custom policies.

#### 3 Upload the ClientCredentialsFlow

The [ClientCredentialsFlow.xml](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/client_credentials_flow/ClientCredentialsFlow.xml) policy can now be uploaded. Make sure you replace the tenant name with yours.

#### Login using application client ID and secret

Login and you should receive an enriched token. You can start customizing the example policy accordingly.

```py
    url = "https://<yourtenant>.b2clogin.com/<yourtenant>.onmicrosoft.com" + 
          "/B2C_1A_DEMO_CLIENTCREDENTIALSFLOW/oauth2/v2.0/token"

    #the scope as described,typically it looks like this
    scope = "https://<yourtenant>.onmicrosoft.com/<resource server id>/.default"

    response = requests.post( url,
            data={'grant_type':'client_credentials', 
                  'client_id':client, 
                  'client_secret':secret, 
                  'scope':scope},
            headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        )
```