# Graph Client - Azure AD JWT Custom Claims

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, claims

**I'm trying to set up custom claims for Client Credentials auth flow in Azure AD.**

**Using Graph Client in C#.**

**However, I do not get my claim in token.**

**The flow I'm using currently is following:**

1. Create an Application
2. Create Service Principal
3. Create Extension Property on Application
4. Create Claims Mapping Policy
5. Add Additional Data to Application - assign value to extension property
6. Assign Claims Mapping Policy to Service Principal

**Creating extension property:**

```
await _graphClient.Applications[app.Id].ExtensionProperties.Request()
    .AddAsync(new ExtensionProperty
    {
        Name = policyName,
        DataType = "String",
        TargetObjects = new List<string> { "Application" }
    });
```

**Creating Claims Mapping Policy:**

```
string appClientIdFormatted = clientId.Replace("-", null);

var claimsMappingPolicy = new ClaimsMappingPolicy
{
    Definition = new List<String>()
    {
        "{" +
           "\"ClaimsMappingPolicy\":{" +
                "\"Version\":1," +
                "\"IncludeBasicClaimSet\":\"true\", " +
                "\"ClaimsSchema\": [" +
                    "{" +
                        "\"Source\":\"application\"," +
                        $"\"ExtensionID\":\"extension_{appClientIdFormatted}_{policyName}\"," +
                        $"\"JwtClaimType\":\"{policyName}\"" +
                    "}" +
                "]" +
            "}" +
        "}"
    },
    DisplayName = displayName,
    IsOrganizationDefault = true
};

await _graphClient.Policies.ClaimsMappingPolicies.Request()
            .AddAsync(claimsMappingPolicy);
```

**Assigning value to extension property**

```
var clientIdFormatted = app.AppId.Replace("-", null);

await _graphClient.Applications[app.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(new Application
{
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { $"extension_{clientIdFormatted}_{policyName}", tenantId }
    }
});
```

**Is there something I'm missing?**

Answer (score 1):

**Please **note** that, by using Client Credentials auth flow adding any additional custom claims is not supported for now.**

If you need custom claim in the token, you have to use either **[Authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)**, **[ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)**, **[Implicit flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow)** authentication flows to generate the token by referring the [***SO Thread***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72543025/add-custom-value-in-upn-claim-in-access-token-generated-using-azure-ad-client-cr/72544673#72544673) which was solved by me.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and added the custom claim.***

After generating the token using **Client Credentials auth flow**, I decoded the token via [**jwt.ms**](https://jwt.ms/) and the custom claim which I created was not included in the response like below:

[image]

To confirm the above, please **refer** below links:

[Add custom claims to azure b2c client credentials flow by **Jas Suri - MSFT**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70798243/add-custom-claims-to-azure-b2c-client-credentials-flow)

[Add custom claims to azure b2c client credentials flow by **ShwetaMathur**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/704387/add-custom-claims-to-azure-b2c-client-credentials.html)