# Unable to set client claims when acquiring confidential client application token

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, azure-app-registration

I am attempting to use the MSAL python library to call another custom api in Azure(Exposed through AppRegistration with an API scope exposed).

I am writing a daemon application that will make the request.
Following Azure documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-app-configuration?tabs=python

The last example on this Azure docs suggests you can add assertions about custom claims such as `client_ip` that would be returned in the token.

Similarly, I would like the `preferred_username` claim to be set to `Test` as an example:

```py
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    config["client_id"], authority=config["authority"],
    client_credential={"thumbprint": config["thumbprint"], "private_key": open(
        config['private_key_file']).read()},
    client_claims={"preferred_username": "Test"}
)
```

However, When I acquire the token using the following code, the `preferred_username` claim is not within the Token.

```py
result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=config["scope"])
```

Within the app registration for the daemon app I have added `preferred_username` as an optional claim (for access tokens).

I am not sure what is wrong with my approach or if I have misinterpreted the intent of `client_claims`?

Comment: Did you Add the optional claim in the Token configuration in Azure Portal?

Comment: @Rukmini yes, I have added the `preferred_username` optional claim for in the Azure portal (in the App Registration for the Daemon App).

Comment: So just to confirm are you using client_credential grant type? Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72867440/graph-client-azure-ad-jwt-custom-claims/72880453#72880453 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72543025/add-custom-value-in-upn-claim-in-access-token-generated-using-azure-ad-client-cr/72544673#72544673

Comment: @Rukmini I'm using client credential flow. 

However, the microsoft documentation I linked (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-app-configuration?tabs=python) suggests I can set custom values for claims such as `preferred_username`. 

I have followed what is said in this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72543025/add-custom-value-in-upn-claim-in-access-token-generated-using-azure-ad-client-cr/72544673#72544673).

I am still unsure how I can use it to allow my Daemon app to set a custom value for `preferred_username `.

Comment: It's not about MSAL, are you using user flows or custom policies? Your Relaying Party must add the corresponding claims to the final Token in your workflow. Are u using AAD or B2C?

Comment: @JuanmaFeliu I am using user flows with AAD

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created an Azure AD Application and configured custom **`preferred_username`** claim:

[image]

I generated the token via Postman by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

***Optional claims are not included in the token like below:***

[image]

> **Note** that:  Getting optional claim is only possible with **[Authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)**, **[ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)**,  **[Implicit flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow)**. Currently, Client Credentials flow does not support adding any additional custom claims.

Client Credentials flow fetch the token in the application's context and won't have any user-related claims like `preferred_username`, `given_name` or `email`, etc. So, you have to generate the token in the user's context to get the claims.

**Alternatively**, I generated the Access Token using the endpoint like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=ClientID&response_type=token&redirect_uri=redirecturi&scope=user.read&response_mode=fragment&state=12345&nonce=678910
```

Optional claims are included in the token like below:

[image]

**Reference:**

[Client assertions (MSAL) - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-client-assertions)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, however this does not solve how to get this token using the MSAL Python library which I would like to do. The endpoint used in your `Alternatively` example has a redirect parameter which a Daemon app does not have.

Comment: Please check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/113893/optinal-34upn34-claim-missed-in-token-requested-by.html